# Rolling file is not creating the next day and previous day file is being written with new logs

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I have implemented log4j2 to log my records each day in a new file. But on next day previous day file is getting new records and old records file is getting archived. Instead of creating a new file with today's date. Once I restart the server, a new file with today's date gets created.

```
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="LogToRollingFile"
        fileName="logs/validategoods/appHeader-${env:hostName}-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
        filePattern="logs/validategoods/${env:hostName}-${date:yyyy-MM}/appHeader-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">

        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d %p [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            <!-- <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern> -->
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy  interval="1"/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />

        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>

    <RollingFile name="LogToRollingFile1"
        fileName="logs/validategoods/appPayload-${env:hostName}-${date:yyyy-MM-dd.HH-mm}.log"
        filePattern="logs/validategoods/${env:hostName}-${date:yyyy-MM}/appPayload-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d %p [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy  interval="1" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />

        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
    <Async name="Async">
        <AppenderRef ref="LogToRollingFile" /> 
    </Async>
    <Async name="Async">
        <AppenderRef ref="LogToRollingFile1" />
    </Async>

</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <!-- avoid duplicated logs with additivity=false -->
    <Logger name="no.posten.header" level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="LogToRollingFile" />
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="no.posten.payload" level="info"
        additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="LogToRollingFile1" />
    </Logger>
    <Root level="debug">

    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

I want to get a new file created each day without restarting the server.